# ~/!(test1|test2) causes syntax error in bashrc, works in command line

Tags: bash

I stripe down my script to the following:

```
search() {
    grep foobar ~/!(test1|test2)
}
```

Very straight forward. I want to create a procedure that grep text `foobar`, but don't grep in test1 or test2 folder

If I simply run this in bash command line, it works as expected(!). Procedure is created and can be called:

```
boyang@vbox-ubuntu:~$ search
grep: /home/boyang/Code/analytics.jpg: Is a directory
/home/boyang/Code/bash_includes:    grep foobar ~/Code/!(test1|test2)
```

If I put this in a script (e.g. `bash_includes`), and source it in .bashrc:

```
if [ -f ~/bash_includes ]; then
    . ~/bash_includes
fi
```

it gives:

```
bash: /home/boyang/bash_includes: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/boyang/bash_includes: line 2: `    grep foobar ~/!(test1|test2)'
```

I tried adding shebang, tried adding quotes (`"~/!(test1|test2)"` or `'~/!(test1|test2)'` or `` \`~/!(test1|test2)\` ``). Nothing works

I'm not a bash expert, but this is puzzling. What am I missing?

Ubuntu 14.04 Bash 4.3.11(1)-release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is only syntactically valid if [extglobs](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language) are enabled. Use `shopt -s extglob` to enable them:

```
shopt -s extglob
search() {
    grep foobar ~/!(test1|test2)
}
```

Presumably your init files were already running this command (such that extglobs were ultimately turned on for your interactive session), but *after* the function's definition.

Comment: It works. adding the line or moving it to the bottom fix it